# IDL set value to cell

Tags: envi

I am writing test app, that should read file name and print it in cell of spreadsheet. I can't understand how to put filename value to cell. Here is my code:

```
PRO test
;D:\Proj\2\test1\data\HTML5_Logo_256.png
title='my example'
base = WIDGET_BASE(xsize=500, ysize=400, MBAR=mbar, TITLE=title, COLUMN=3, TLB_FRAME_ATTR=1)
fmenu = WIDGET_BUTTON(mbar, VALUE='File')  
open_file = WIDGET_BUTTON(fmenu, value='Open file', uvalue='Open')
table = WIDGET_TABLE(base, XSIZE=4, YSIZE=4, COLUMN_LABELS=["name", "FID", "size", "foo"], X_SCROLL_SIZE=0)

WIDGET_CONTROL, base, /REALIZE
info={base:base}
infoptr=PTR_NEW(info)
WIDGET_CONTROL, base, SET_UVALUE=infoptr
XMANAGER,'test', base,/NO_BLOCK
END

PRO test_EVENT, event

WIDGET_CONTROL,event.top, GET_UVALUE=infoptr
info=*infoptr
WIDGET_CONTROL,event.id, GET_UVALUE=widget

IF (widget EQ 'Open') THEN BEGIN 
  filename=DIALOG_PICKFILE(PATH='D:\Proj\2')
  envi_open_file, filename, r_fid=fid

  if (fid eq -1) then return

ENVI_FILE_QUERY, fid, filename=filename, ns=ns

print,'filename=',filename
WIDGET_CONTROL, table, SET_VALUE = filename ; here is my attempt


ENDIF

END
```